# How can I delete old Gradle files and JDKs downloaded by IntelliJ on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, gradle, intellij-idea, settings

I am using IntelliJ IDEA for programming with Gradle on Linux. The problem is, IntelliJ (for some reason) could not detect my Gradle I downloaded myself (version 7.4), so it tried to download one itself (version 7.1) and I couln't stop it. I tried tweaking around a bit and in the end IntelliJ decided it needed one more version, the one it downloaded earlier wasn't enough, so it downloaded version 7.2. After a while I managed to command IntelliJ to use the Gradle I downloaded, but now I am left with two Gradles I don't want to use (versions 7.1 and 7.2). How can I delete them?

Also, IntelliJ downloaded a JDK when I already had one (same story), and it just occupies space. Is there any way to delete it as well?

I can't find any files for neither of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find JDKs location go to `File | Project Structure | SDKs | select downloaded JDK | JDK home path`. Open the mentioned path is OS file explorer and delete the folder.

Regarding the Gradle issue. For now, there is no way to disable gradle wrapper generation by default. Feel free to vote/follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-215792 . Downloaded distributions can be removed from `~/.gradle/wrapper/dists`.

Comment: I found the path for the jdk, thanks. Now I only have one question left, how do I know which one to delete? IntelliJ shows some weird folder names and it is quite specific. It only wants me to delete a folder named "jbr", when the parent folder contains folders much larger than it (e.g. jbr is 315M, lib is 539M and plugins is 1.8G with some other ones totaling 2.7G). Is it safe to delete the whole parent folder?

Answer (score 1):

Normally *IntelliJ* installed *JDK* is inside *IntelliJ* installation folder in a subfolder named `jbr`.  Gradle will be in `plugins` subfolder. If you want to remove them, delete the folders.

Comment: so what does the plugins folder contain? is it safe to delete it as well (my point which could be wrong is that maybe there is another plugins folder for the jdk i'm using)?